# Send data to PC from WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I already know how to send data (image and string) from WP7 to PC.
But my problem its how I send 2 string (2 data)
this code for send 1 data by socket

```
public string Send(string serverName, int portNumber, string data)
    {
        string response = "Timeout";

if (socket != null)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(serverName, portNumber);

        socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            response = e.SocketError.ToString();
            clientDone.Set();
        });

        byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        socketEventArg.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);
        clientDone.Reset();
        socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);

        clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
    }
    else
    {
        response = "not initialized";
    }
    return response;
}
```

So what modification can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can send 1 string you can send 2 the same way. Just have a delimit the strings and concatenate them together.
You then split them on the other end.

Comment: mmmmmm
nice, can you give an exemple plz